# Metrics for Cognito are not showing up in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

Our team is implementing a Web Application (ReactJS) that utilizes Amazon Cognito service for user sign-up, log-in, log-out.
However, instead of using Cognito's hosted UIs, we created our own login page and used amazon-cognito-identity-js sdk to implement the authentication functionality.

Now, I need to be able to monitor the user activity (for example, which users logged-in from which location). I understand that this can be done by using Cognito's Advanced Security feature.

I have set the user pool's Advanced Security Setting to "Audit Only". However, there are still no Cognito-related metrics showing up in Cloudwatch.

I also tried to follow the instructions described in below site but to no results.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-viewing-advanced-security-app.html

Does anyone have any idea as to what setting I may have missed out?
Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Cognito will automatically setup Cloudwatch for your User Pool activity. You just need to go to Cloudwatch > Select "Cognito" from the Services list.

Try to refine the time filter or set the refresh interval to make Cloudwatch regularly fetch the newest metrics.

Hope this answers.